# Jest und Meteor: Error While processing files with templating-compiler

Tags: meteor, jestjs

I have a meteor object with the following structure:

```
+ .meteor
+ client
- coverage
   - lcov-report
       index.html
       ...
+ imports
+ node_modules
+ private
+ public
+ server
...
```

My problem is, if I try starting the meteor App, I get following error:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While processing files with templating-compiler (for target web.browser):
   coverage/lcov-report/index.html:2: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets
   <!DOCTYPE html> for you)

   While processing files with templating-compiler (for target
   web.browser.legacy):
   coverage/lcov-report/index.html:2: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets
   <!DOCTYPE html> for you)

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Started MongoDB.
```

So it seems to be related with the jest integration. Do you have an idea, how to solve it? I am using MacOS. I already chmod 777 coverage folder (and sub-items) but without success.

Thanks in advance for your time and best regards,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it by creating a '.meteorignore' file in the root of the project. Then I added 'coverage/' to the file (syntax as you would do it for .gitignore).

Hope it helps you, too.

Best,
Christian